# Not good stream at opening?

Tags: c++, file, stream, standard-library

When I open a file in binary mode, does a situation exist where `is_open()` is `true` but `good()` is `false` ?

```
bool ok = false;
std::ifstream stream("test.dat", std::ios::binary)
if (stream.is_open())
{
    ok = stream.good();//Does a situation exist where the result of this is false ?
    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: I think if the file is empty, `good()` may return false, but it is not guaranteed to until the first read attempt.

Comment: No, but any i/o operation after the is_open() call could set the bad, fail or eof bits.

Comment: @Prætorian if the file is empty, the eof bit wont be set unitl an i/o operation is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: the two-argument constructor of `std::ifstream` is required to set the failbit if file opening fails.

> §27.9.1.7[ifstream.cons]/2
>
> `explicit basic_ifstream(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in);`
>
> calls `rdbuf()->open(s, mode | ios_base::in)`. If that function returns a null pointer, calls `setstate(failbit)`.

and, for open(),

> §27.9.1.4[filebuf.members]/2
>
> `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>* open(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode);`
>
> Returns: `this` if successful, a null pointer otherwise